# Create a string with special character in R

Tags: r, string, character, paste

I have an issue creating a string with a special character. I have asked a similar question and I have also read answers to similar questions about my problem but I am not able to find the solution.

I want to create a `string` character with a special character. I have been trying with `cat` but I know it is only for printing, not for saving the string in a variable in R.

I want as a result this:

```
> cat("C:\\Users\\ppp\\ddd\\")
C:\Users\ppp\ddd\
```

and I have been trying with `paste` and `collapse` but without success:

```
> x = c("C:","Users","ppp","ddd")
> t <- paste0(x, collapse = '\n')
> t
[1] "C:\nUsers\nppp\nddd"
```

Comment: you should use `file.path` and not `paste`: `file.path("C:","Users","ppp","ddd")`

Comment: I do not want a working directory for R. I want to create a string.

Comment: that's what it does

Comment: yes, but to create a string with this \ as separation, not this /

Comment: 1) `/` works on windows, 2) `file.path` will chose the correct default separator for your OS, that is one reason it is superior to `paste`, 3) you can override the default separator, you should read the help file for `?file.path`

Comment: I do not want to create a file.path. I want to save the string and after import in Matlab that for the file paths use \ instead of /

Comment: _a file path is a string is a file path is a string_

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want

```
x = c("C:","Users","ppp","ddd")
t <- paste0(x, collapse = '/')
t
[1] "C:/Users/ppp/ddd"
```

R uses this format for setting working directories.

You can also do:

```
x = c("C:","Users","ppp","ddd")
t <- paste0(x, collapse = '\\')
t
[1] "C:\\Users\\ppp\\ddd"
```

Although this result looks wrong, if you are using the string in a shell() command in R to be interpreted Windows for example, it will be interpreted correctly

Comment: I know how the working directory works in R, but I want in the way I explained for MATLAB

Comment: If it's going to MATLAB can't you store it in a way that works in R, and then change it in your MATLAB code?

Answer (score 0):

Not Answering... but

```
t <- paste0(x, collapse = '/')
```

"C:/Users/ppp/ddd"  seems to work on windows.